# Blender: How to export mesh with LODs in GLTF for the unreal engine?

Tags: export, blender, unreal-engine4, gltf, unreal-engine5

I know how to export a mesh with LODs in `FBX` for the unreal engine.

- First parent mesh and LODs to an `Empty`.
- Add a custom property of string `fbx_type` and value `LodGroup` to the `Empty`.
- Select `Empty` and its children and export.

But when I do the same for `GLTF`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

LODs are not included in the glTF specification, but are part of a Microsoft extension, [MSFT-lod](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/main/extensions/2.0/Vendor/MSFT_lod).

To export a glTF from Blender using this extension, you need to use a Blender add-on, such as [glTF-Blender-IO-MSFT-lod](https://github.com/takahirox/glTF-Blender-IO-MSFT-lod).

However, Unreal Engine currently does not support this extension. They list their supported glTF extensions [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/gltf-file-format-support-in-unreal-engine/). The developer of the glTFRuntime plugin for Unreal Engine did mention that it is on the to-do list to implement LOD [here](https://github.com/rdeioris/glTFRuntime/issues/3), but I don’t believe it has been so far.